# Visual Studio Code - .net core - generate xml documentation

Tags: swagger, visual-studio-code, xml-documentation

We are using `Swagger UI` documentation to describe our project API. Swagger have to read XML from `projectname.xml` to show all the C.R.U.D. functions we have in project.

The problem is when I switch from Visual Studio to Visual Studio Code, it is not regenerating or changing existing XML file from Visual Studio Code. Is there the way to generate XML documentation file in Visual Studio Code like in Visual Studio Ultimate for instance, as shown the image below?

[image: visual studio xml documentation file]

Comment: write tests rather than auto generated crap that no one will ever read or find useful.

Comment: tests are cool, and even so, i would like to know the answer to a question :)

Comment: tests are far from cool. But they can be great documentation.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `<GenerateDocumentationFile>` property in the project file. This is a Boolean, and sets the `DocumentationFile` property automatically.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(Unfortunately, the Visual Studio project properties UI doesn't expose this improved way to enable XML documentation file generation yet. See [this work item](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/368) in the project system repo, and [this pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/349), which initially added the feature.)

Answer (score 5):

The following is slightly more robust, it doesn't hard code the framework and project

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\$(TargetFramework)\$(MSBuildProjectName).xml</DocumentationFile>
  <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

See [David Waterworth's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49904879/22233) answer as it is more robust.

In your csproj file for the project, add the following.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
 <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\TodoApi.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then rebuild your project.