# Swagger documentation from XML doesn't show schema for in query object parameter

Tags: visual-studio-code, swagger, xml-documentation

Using an example of REST api with a GET method that takes in an object query parameter.
[image]

VSCode is configured to generate XML documentation and feed it into Swagger like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836489/visual-studio-code-net-core-generate-xml-documentation).
The result swagger page shows documentation for the respective field in the input object
[image]

But, the object data model doesn't show in the Schema section
[image]

If the `[FromQuery]` gets removed from the method signature, the data model gets included in the schema
[image]

But the endpoint request body is used instead of query parameter which is not the wanted behavior.
[image]

The XML file generated in both scenarios is the same

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>DateTimeServiceAPI</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="P:DateTimeServiceAPI.DTOs.GetCurrentTimeDTO.TenantId">
            <summary>
            indentifer of the tenant
            </summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

Any idea why is this difference in generating the documentation? I couldn't find anything relevant while searching about this.

How can I (force) include all data models in the schema section?
Any pointers or resources are highly appreciated.

Thank you

---

Update:
In the RESTfull api guide [here](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/), section 7. REST Basics - URLs:
[image]
Is it against best practices to use DTOs as query parameters?

Comment: you can add any model to schema collection check this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73202013/9247039)

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `GetCurrentTimeDTO` model, the properties of a DTO that's used as a parameter to a controller method should have `public` set, if it is `internal` or `private` Swagger won't show it.

```
public class MyDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; } // Not shown
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } //shown
}
```

Comment: DTO class and its fields are all public.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you tried to explicitly include documentation in swagger?

Comment: yes, xml documentation is fed into swagger just like the attached picture