# Need to add existing model (not inline) to Swagger schemas in .Net core API

Tags: .net, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I am generating Swagger document for my .Net core 6 based API. I have some error models which will be returned by my Gateway. These are not used/returned in any of my API endpoints. I want to add these models to Swagger document schema collection. I am able to successfully add them if I follow inline way. Is there a way to include existing models in Swagger schema collection?

I also want to include webhook models and examples to schemas collection without going through inline option.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can put any example which model you want to add to schema ?

Comment: @CodingMytra - thank you for your comment. I have created a model (ex: GWErrorModel.cs) like below. I want to inject this into schema collection, so that I can refer it in all responses of all my endpoints.

public class GWErrorModel
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do following to add the model to schema collection.

Create a custom document filter

```
public class CustomDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(GWErrorModel), context.SchemaRepository);
    }
}
```

add it to program.cs

```
   builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
   {
      o.DocumentFilter<CustomDocumentFilter>();
   });
```

you will see the model is added to schema collection.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much for the answer, sample code and your time.

Comment: Perfect, worked great in .Net 6 for me